# "No compatible constructor" on custom Ant task?

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to write a custom task for Apache Ant (following [this tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)).

Currently, my task looks like this:

```
package my.package;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Task;

class MyTask extends Task
{
    private String command;

    public void setCommand(String command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
        System.out.println(command);
    }
}
```

I use the task in my buildfile as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TaskExample" default="main" basedir=".">
  <taskdef name="mytask" classname="my.package.MyTask"/>

  <target name="main">
    <mytask command="foobar" />
  </target>
</project>
```

When calling Ant, I get the following error:

```
> ant -lib .
Buildfile: /path/to/build.xml

main:

BUILD FAILED
/path/to/build.xml:6: Could not create type mytask as the class class my.package.MyTask has no compatible constructor

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution while still typing the question. But maybe this will be of use to someone else:

I simply forgot the `public` qualifier in the class declaration. So declaring the class as follows works perfectly:

```
package my.package;

// ...

// Mind the "public"!
public class MyTask extends Task
{
    // ...
}
```